# Delete all but largest file in multiple directories

Tags: bash, files, scripting

I have multiple subdirectories in `/home/usr/ProjZ/programs/` that each contain multiple (or one) `.js` files.

What I need to do is delete all but the largest `.js` file, if the subdirectory contains multiple files, or do nothing if the subdirectory only contains one `.js` file.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Is there a particular part of the problem you are stuck on?

Comment: I'm pretty new to using linux and I guess it's that I just don't understand what tools I should use to approach the problem.  I would like to write a bash script unless there is a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
for dir (/home/usr/ProjZ/programs/*(/)) rm -f $dir/*.js(.NOL[2,-1])
```

Note that if there are several files with the biggest size, only one will be retained. Which one that will be depends on the order they appear in the current directory (which generally is more or less random).

GNUly (recent GNU `sed` for `-z`), the equivalent would look like:

```
for dir in /home/usr/ProjZ/programs/*; do
  [ -d "$dir" && ! -L "$dir" ] || continue
  find "$dir" -type f -printf '%s:%p\0' | sort -rzn |
    sed -z '1d;s/[^:]*://' | xargs -r0 rm -f
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me if the .js files are all in a single directory, or if they exist anywhere underneath that point.

If you just want to remove all but the largest .js from a single directory, you can do something like this:

```
$ ls -S *.js | tail --lines=+2 | xargs rm
```

This isn't safe if the files have odd characters like whitespace.

If the .js can exist at any depth, I'd probably script it.

perl

```
use File::Find;
find(\&wanted, "/path/to/look/in");
my $biggest_file;
my $biggest_size = 0;
sub wanted {
  if ($_ =~ /\.js$/) {
    my ($size) = (stat $_)[7];
    if ($size > $biggest_size) {
      unlink $biggest_file if defined $biggest_file;
      $biggest_size = $size;
      $biggest_file = $File::Find::name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The first one assumes a GNU `ls`, a GNU `tail`, that .js files are not of type directory, that their name don't start with `-` don't contain blank or quote or backslash characters.

Comment: Sorry, the first part of my comment is inaccurate as `-S`, though initially a GNU extension has now been specified by POSIX.

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers but I rather keep it simple and do it in `bash`. Especially if you're a newbie.

Here's how I'll do it with some comments to help you follow along:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Loop through all subdirectories
for dir in $(find /home/usr/ProjZ/programs/ -type d)
do

    # Get all .js files in this subdir
    files=$(find $dir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.js')

    # If there's no files in here, just skip this subdir
    if [ -z "$files" ]
    then
        continue
    fi

    # Get deletion candidates (sort by size, remove the biggest, get filenames)
    rm_candidates=$(stat -c "%s %n" ${files} | sort -n | head -n -1 | cut -d" " -f2-)

    # Finally, remove each file
    for file in $rm_candidates
    do
        rm -f $file
    done
done
```

Comment: That's neither simple nor reliable nor portable and has a few bad coding practice. You could at least point out the limitations of that solution.

Comment: I suppose simple is subjective. Feel free to comment on portability. I tried to use common utilities and avoid `xargs`.

Comment: `head -n -1` is not portable. That's GNU `stat` syntax. `-maxdepth` is also a GNU extension (though also supported by a few other `find`s). You're using the split+glob operator without fixing the separator and disabling the glob part. So it assumes the file names don't contain blank/newline/wildcard characters.

Comment: Good catches, +1. Can you elaborate on the split glob part? Thought I covered my bases on whitespace but didn't get a chance to test.

Comment: Leaving a variable or a command substitution unquoted in list context is the split+glob operator, that's why your loops are looping on something, but there's looping on the words resulting from filename generation applied to the words resulting from the splitting on the characters in `$IFS`.

Comment: Doh, thanks!! Didn't catch that. Appreciate the input (pun not intended).

Answer (score 0):

This little bash script will handle correctly when the .js file may have spaces in the name, and where the directories may contain both .js files and other extensions.

```
#!/bin/bash
find /home/usr/ProjZ/programs/* -type d | while read "x"; do
NUMFILES=`ls -1 "$x"/*.js | wc -l`
[[ $NUMFILES -gt 2 ]] && ls -1Sr "$x"/*.js 2>/dev/null | head -n $(($NUMFILES-2)) | xargs -I{} rm -f "{}"
done 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: No, it will not work at all as written.

Comment: I just ran it on my CentOS just fine. Did you get an error, or are you just 'guessing' it won't work?

Comment: `xargs -I{} rm -f \"{}\"` will try to remove files whose name start and end in `"` characters so cannot work.

Comment: My bad, copy and paste error, the backslash is not needed. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: It will still fail if directory names contain blanks or newline or wildcard characters or backslash or if file paths contain quotes or backslashes or if there are js files of type directory. Note that the `-S` option to `ls`, initially a GNU extension is not available everywhere as it's a recent addition to the POSIX specification for `ls` (not in Solaris 10 `ls` for instance).

Comment: Interesting, I wasn't pondering the directories.  Surrounding the directory variable will fix spaces.  I think the OP has much bigger issues than a large js file if there are wildcard characters in the directory or file names ;-)